# why does metal have positive charge in normal position?

Tags: electricity

is that right to say metal has positive charge in normal position?

if not, so why does electricity pass through my body when I touch the doorknob?

why does some stuff have extra electron or some others have positive charge? like when I put my foot on rug it conducts electron to my foot, and my foot gives the extra to the earth through my body, if the whole charge of the earth is neutral, why does some parts or some stuff on it are not neutral?

and in the end, why do I get electrical shock? is that a huge number of electrons pass through my body?

Comment: What do you mean by "normal position"?

Comment: @probably_someone a position in which stuffs don't exchange electrons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by "normal position" you mean "equilibrium", then no. All materials attempt to become neutral in equilibrium. If you were to touch a bunch of pieces of metal, a small positive charge is as likely as a small negative charge.

The reason you get shocked is probably because *you* are charged, especially if you just walked across a carpet.

Before you start walking across it, the carpet is also very close to being neutral. It's misleading to say that the carpet "conducts" electrons to your foot, because that implies that there are free electrons waiting to flow into you. That's not the case for a carpet, which is a insulator that holds onto its electrons tightly. What's happening here is a phenomenon called triboelectricity - electrons are being forcibly ripped from the carpet by friction with your body. Now that these electrons are in your body, they produce an electric field which induces an electric dipole in the metal knob. Negative charges are pushed away and so the knob's tip becomes positively charged, attracting the electrons in your body. When you get close enough, the electrons jump from your body to the knob, producing a spark and a painful shock.

Comment: what happens in triboelectricity ? why does my body get the carpet's electrons by force?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triboelectric_effect

Comment: thank you, another question, tell me if it's answered in the wikipedia article i haven't read it yet, why does metal give electrical shock when we have negative charge and why not when we have positive charge?

Comment: What do you mean? It shocks with both.

Comment: i mean metal is likely to attract extra electron and carpet is likely to give away extra electron. or maybe I was taught wrongly !

Comment: I mean, yes, that's usually the way that it happens in that very particular scenario, but that doesn't mean it always works that way.